# How to cache paged queries using memcache in gae, ndb?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm having a really difficult time figuring out how can I cache a paged query.

I'm building a Forum with ndb and gae. The front page is the default forum with a limited amount of posts and a Next button to load more posts.

This posts are retrieved with ndb fetch_page and I found that is really common for the users to navigate through pages. So instead of querying the datastore for every user request I would like to store each page in memcache and let it do the work.

I tried to do it and I can only cache the next pages, but not the previous ones.

Also, I don't know how to invalidate all cached results when a user creates a new post.

Anyone can help?

**EDIT:**

The following code returns 10 records of any class given a bookmark (a urlsafe of a cursor).

How can y cache every page considering that must work going forward and backwards and you can invalidate all the queries cached for a given query for example when the user puts a new record.

```
def return_query_page(cls, size=10, bookmark=None, is_prev=None, equality_filters=None, orders=None):
    """
    Generate a paginated result on any class
    Param cls: The ndb model class to query
    Param size: The size of the results
    Param bokkmark: The urlsafe cursor of the previous queries. First time will be None
    Param is_prev: If your requesting for a next result or the previous ones
    Param equal_filters: a dictionary of {'property': value} to apply equality filters only
    Param orders: a dictionary of {'property': '-' or ''} to order the results like .order(cls.property)
    Return: a tuple (list of results, Previous cursor bookmark, Next cursor bookmark)
    """
    if bookmark:
        cursor = ndb.Cursor(urlsafe=bookmark)
    else:
        is_prev = None
        cursor = None

    q = cls.query()
    try:
        for prop, value in equality_filters.iteritems():
            q = q.filter(cls._properties[prop] == value)

        q_forward = q.filter()
        q_reverse = q.filter()

        for prop, value in orders.iteritems():
            if value == '-':
                q_forward = q_forward.order(-cls._properties[prop])
                q_reverse = q_reverse.order(cls._properties[prop])
            else:
                q_forward = q_forward.order(cls._properties[prop])
                q_reverse = q_reverse.order(-cls._properties[prop])
    except:
        return None, None, None
    if is_prev:
        qry = q_reverse
        new_cursor = cursor.reversed() if cursor else None
    else:
        qry = q_forward
        new_cursor = cursor if cursor else None

    results, new_cursor, more = qry.fetch_page(size, start_cursor=new_cursor)
    if more and new_cursor:
        more = True
    else:
        more = False

    if is_prev:
        prev_bookmark = new_cursor.reversed().urlsafe() if more else None
        next_bookmark = bookmark
        results.reverse()
    else:
        prev_bookmark = bookmark
        next_bookmark = new_cursor.urlsafe() if more else None

    return results, prev_bookmark, next_bookmark
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about exactly what you've tried. I would recommend including a code snippet with your code that tries to do the caching.

Comment: The answer below is probably your best one.  Any other strategy will mean you will have difficulty/impossible to invalidate the cache for individual keys as you point out in your question.  If cache invalidation for individual entities is not a problem then summarize the result set and store it as a single memcache entry.  But if the no one goes backwards or re-uses the pagination for this particular query then any caching will be of little or no use.

Comment: But with this approach you will always have the query only keys cost. That's the only inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be better off using a keys_only query and then doing a key.get() on each returned key.

That way, memcache will be used for each post.

Example (assuming Post is the model):

```
keys, cursor, more = Post.query().fetch_page(30, start_cursor=cursor, keys_only=True)
entities = ndb.get_multi(keys)
```

Comment: This have been talked a lot and is not a valid solution for me. See: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=118

Comment: Why isn't it a valid solution.  It is effectively what you want.  Yes the experiment showed in many cases it was not performant.  If the cases where it didn't perform well in the experiment apply to you, then you caching scheme is unlikely to perform any better.  THe performance benefit in the experiment will only high if you have a high cache hit ratio, and the same will apply for any caching you do.

Comment: ok, maybe I can combine this with caching the hole first page. I accept the answer as valid.